# Magento 2.4.6 Trying to access array offset on value of type null .../framework/...Subscription.php

Tags: magento2.4.6

I upgraded Magento version from V2.4.3 to v2.4.6 and got this error when run setup:upgrade
***Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in vendor/magento/framework/Mview/View/Subscription.php on line 345***

[image]